# why there are two classes for handling request in Struts 1.3 , ActionServlet and RequestProcessor

Tags: struts-1

Why in **struts 1.3** we have two separated classes for handling request :

> -- ActionServlet which intercept the request and calls RequestProcessors process method for further processing
>   --RequestProcessor read XML file, find the appropriate Handler and handles request

My question is why this are two different classes?
I tried to search on the net and books but did not got any answer.

Can any one have any idea? please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActionServlet` basically reads your `struts-config.xml` and creates a `ModuleConfig`. This `ModuleConfig` is a Object representation of your `struts-config.xml`. ActionServlet just passes your `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpSerlvetResponse` to the `RequestProcessor`.

The `RequestProcessor` basically identifies the `Action` from the request (through the `ModuleConfig` helper) create an `ActionMapping` (based on the call one made) and performs executes the necessary action to retrieve an `ActionForward`. From the `ActionForward`, it delegates your request and response to it and that's the whole Struts workflow.

Basically, the heart of Struts is through the `RequestProcessor`. The `ActionServlet` just initializes Struts as well as passes the request and response to the `RequestProcessor`.

Comment: Hi Elite,Thanks for reply ,But i want to know why not they(Struts developer) combine both task in single class, why separate classes?

Comment: Because they wanted it to be modular. RequestProcessor not only deals with Servlet, but also Plugins, interceptors, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The **RequestProcessor** Class is the actual place where the request processing takes place in a Struts controller environment.

When the request object first reaches the **actionservlet** class then it invokes the **process** method of the underlying RequestProcessor Class.

This process method then looks into the **struts-config.xml** file and tries to locate the name of the action that has come with the request.Once it identifies the action in the xml file it continues the rest of the steps needed for request processing.